# About git read write permission?

Tags: git

For a git repository, if I have read-only permission, can I create a branch and modify the source code in my branch?  Or do I have to fork the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  I believe what you're asking is "if there is a read-only repo on disk, can you add your own branch to it?"  No.  The metadata area generally all has the same permissions.  You'll need to clone it, and make the change in your fork.